# Do I have to replace my expansion tank, or can it be drained?

Tags: boiler

I have no heating. My plumber tells me that my expansion tank has water in it and should not be hot and therefore needs replacing (expensive job). is this true. Can the water not be drained out?

Greenstar highflow 440 combi boiler

Comment: I am sorry but your question is very difficult to answer. As you already had a professional in we can only give advice; but you do not ask anything specific. I would suggest calling 2 or 3 more plumbers and asking them to quote you. Please do not be discouraged and try asking a more specific, technical question when the times comes again.

Comment: Right. But in general terms, if there's water, there's something wrong. If you drain the water without fixing the problem, the water will return.

Answer (score 3):

I have a gas hot water base board system with an expansion tank. The tank has a drain valve to which I can attach a garden hose. I drain the tank at the beginning of the heating system and check it on occasion. If the gas boiler pressure rises quickly then the expansion tank probably needs draining. I may drain mine once over the winter. I don't understand why your expansion tank does not have a means of draining but if it is fairly good condition I think it would be much easier to install one than replace the tank. If you go with replacement get one with a way to drain it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to offer you advice on the technical problem at hand as there's really no way to know. So I'm going to answer your please help by advising you to get a second opinion.

Call a different heating engineer and get them to look into the problem without telling them anyone has already looked at it or what was found. If your second opinion is the same as the first then I'd go with the replacement with whichever of the two gave you a better quote. If the second opinion disagrees with the first then you will have to determine which is better. Generally the cheaper course is the more advisable one.